# Find all elements with specific data attribute if their val() is not undifined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to initialize an  array of elements, that have specific data attribute. But only the elements that have value should be in array (the elements can be select, input and etc.)
**UPDATE:** for example: if the element is text input and has not value, or, if the element is select but no option is selected by user, it shouldn't be added to array.
how should I modify the array below?

```
var myArr = element.find('[data-filter-field]')
```

Comment: add html mark up as well

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: What is the final result you expect. And what is the problem now. Please make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.filter` to filter elements with value

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function(){
  var inputs = $("[data-filter-field]").filter(function(){
  return !!this.value
  });
  
  $.each(inputs, function(i,el){
    console.log(el.id)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" data-filter-field="true">
<input id="txt2" data-filter-field="true">
<input id="txt3" data-filter-field="true">
<input id="txt4" data-filter-field="true">
<input id="txt5" data-filter-field="true">

<button id="btn"> Get element Lists </button>
```